# cs50 pset 4 - Filter less - Blur filters middle pixel as 126 instead of 127

Tags: c, cs50

The code incorrectly filters the middle pixel, and it seems to be the only thing that is wrong, and affects everything else. The problem is that I already tried a lot of things, and nothing seems to make it correct. check50 gives me these results:

:( blur correctly filters middle pixel

expected "127 140 149\n", not "126 140 149\n"

:) blur correctly filters pixel on edge

:) blur correctly filters pixel in corner

:( blur correctly filters 3x3 image

expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "70 85 95\n80 9..."

:( blur correctly filters 4x4 image

expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "70 85 95\n80 9..."

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];

for(int h = 0; h < height; h++)
{
    for(int w = 0; w < width; w++)
    {
        copy[h][w] = image[h][w];
    }
}

for(int h = 0; h < (height - 1); h++)
{
    for(int w = 0; w < (width - 1); w++)
    {
        int counter = 0;;

        float averageBlue = 0;
        float averageGreen = 0;
        float averageRed = 0;

        for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
        {
            if ((h + i) >= 0 && (h + i) < height)
            {
                for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
                {
                    if ((w + j) >= 0 || (w + j) < width)
                    {
                        averageBlue += copy[h + i][w + j].rgbtBlue;
                        averageGreen += copy[h + i][w + j].rgbtGreen;
                        averageRed += copy[h + i][w + j].rgbtRed;
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        image[h][w].rgbtBlue = round((float)averageBlue / counter);
        image[h][w].rgbtGreen = round((float)averageGreen / counter);
        image[h][w].rgbtRed = round((float)averageRed / counter);
    }
}
```

(please keep in mind I´m new to programming, 16 years old and english is not my first lenguage)

Comment: Not sure if that could be the reason but you should not use `float` if there is not a good reason to it. Use `double` isntead.

Comment: Shouldn't it be an `&&` operator in this condition: `if ((w + j) >= 0 || (w + j) < width)` ?

Comment: `h < (height - 1)` doesn't that stop 1 pixel too early in each dimension?

Comment: The `float` should be ok here (you aren't really dealing with floating point values anyway), but *in general* (for example in trigonometry or other math) it's good advice to use `double` unless there is a good reason why you must use `float`.